# setting value to hidden_field_tag in HAML

Tags: post, haml, hidden-field

I have a HAML file in which there is a line like follows:

```
 %td
   = hidden_field_tag "item1"
```

I am setting its value in jquery as follows:

```
 $("#item1").val(1)
```

But it is not working, so I have done as follows:

```
 $("#item1").attr("value",1)
```

Even it is not working also. Actually the item tag is associated with a form so while I am posting it, in handler page when I am printing parameters, it is printing as :item =>""

**Edit**: Its HTML source is as follows:

```
<input id="item1" name="item1" type="hidden">
```

No value field is coming.

Comment: What is your current HAML putting out for your sample (what is the HTML source as viewed in your browser)?

Comment: generally, what you have looks fine. I created a sample for you to show reading and setting the value in jQuery here: ***http://jsfiddle.net/T2v8K/2*** . Try setting a default value like this <input id="item1" name="item1" type="hidden" value="defaultValue" /> and see if you properly read out the value in your form post.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, what you have looks fine. I created a sample for you to show reading and setting the value in jQuery here: ***http://jsfiddle.net/T2v8K/2*** . This should help you with debugging.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <form id="myForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>normal input: <input id="newValue" name="newValue" value="1" /></td>
                <td>hidden input: <input id="item1" name="item1" type="hidden" value="someDefaultValue"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button id="showVal" type="button">Show Hidden Input Value</button>
    <button id="setVal" type="button">Set Hidden Input Value</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript / jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var beforeValue = $( "#item1" ).val();
    //alert( "Before = " + beforeValue );

    var afterValue = $( "#item1" ).val();
    //alert( "After = " + afterValue );

    $( "#showVal" ).click( function() {
        ShowHiddenInputValue();
        })

    $( "#setVal" ).click( function() {
        SetHiddenInputValue();
        })

});

function ShowHiddenInputValue() {
    //Show the current value of the hidden input
    var hiddenInputValue = $( "#item1" ).val();
    alert( "Hidden Input Value = " + hiddenInputValue );
}

function SetHiddenInputValue(){
    //Get the value from the input
    var newHiddenInputValue = $( "#newValue" ).val();

    //Set the hidden input
    $( "#item1" ).val(newHiddenInputValue);

    ShowHiddenInputValue();    
}
```

Try setting a default value like this  and see if you properly read out the value in your form post.

Also, if you aren't sure that jQuery is working (perhaps not referenced properly), you can test that by checking for the version number in an alert like this in your JavaScript:

```
alert($().jquery);
```

Comment: Hello? Did you try this?